# Processing JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I'm sorry for the simple question. I'm new to working with JSON and JS.

I have 'fruits.json':

```
      {
        "Apples": {
            "Apples_pos1": 501.82,
            "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
            "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
            "Apples_pos4": 502.16,
        },
        "Bananas": {
            "Bananas_pos1": 495.73,
            "Bananas_pos2": 493.27,
            "Bananas_pos3": 493.38,
            "Bananas_pos4": 494.34,
        },
        "Oranges": {
            "Oranges_pos1": 497.35,
            "Oranges_pos2": 497.31,
            "Oranges_pos3": 498.03,
            "Oranges_pos4": 496.67,
        },
        "Pears": {
            "Pears_pos1": 497.62,
            "Pears_pos2": 498.46,
            "Pears_pos3": 497.54,
            "Pears_pos4": 497.95,
        },
```

I want to call 'fruits.json' and reformat it to look like:

```
[["Apples", 501.82, "Apples_pos1"],
["Apples", 502.61, "Apples_pos2"],
["Apples", 502.61, "Apples_pos3"],
["Apples", 502.16, "Apples_pos4"],
["Bananas", 495.73, "Bananas_pos1"],
["Bananas", 493.27, "Bananas_pos2"],
["Bananas", 493.38, "Bananas_pos3"],
["Bananas", 494.34, "Bananas_pos4"],
["Oranges", 497.35, "Oranges_pos1"],
["Oranges", 497.31, "Oranges_pos2"],
["Oranges", 498.03, "Oranges_pos3"],
["Oranges", 496.67, "Oranges_pos4"],
["Pears", 497.62, "Pears_pos1"],
["Pears", 498.46, "Pears_pos2"],
["Pears", 497.54, "Pears_pos3"],
["Pears", 497.95, "Pears_pos4"]]
```

Currently, I use this function to call the JSON:

```
function retrieveJSON(jsonpath, callback) {
  $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: jsonpath,
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (data) {
      console.log("success");
      callback(data);
    },
    error: function (response) {
      console.log("error");
      console.log(response);
      callback({"error": "!!!!"});
    }
  });
}

document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    let url = window.location;
    let baseURL = url.protocol + "//" + url.host;
     retrieveJSON(baseURL + "/static/json/fruits.json", (json_data) => {
      console.log(json_data);
});
});
```

Any advice on how to reformat the JSON into my desired format after I call it?

Comment: Your desired format is invalid JSON. Can you please check again?

Comment: Do you mean an array of arrays? `[ ["Apples", 501.82, "Apples_pos1"], [], ... ]`

Comment: Use nested loops over the properties of the main object and the properties of the nested objects.

Comment: @AnuragSrivastava  yes I meant an array of arrays. Thanks.

Comment: Can you visit the url where the path is, copy it, and check it as valid JSON with this https://jsonlint.com/ Website

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can try by running [`array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) along with [`Object.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) / [`Object.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries):

```js
let input =  {
        "Apples": {
            "Apples_pos1": 501.82,
            "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
            "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
            "Apples_pos4": 502.16,
        },
        "Bananas": {
            "Bananas_pos1": 495.73,
            "Bananas_pos2": 493.27,
            "Bananas_pos3": 493.38,
            "Bananas_pos4": 494.34,
        },
        "Oranges": {
            "Oranges_pos1": 497.35,
            "Oranges_pos2": 497.31,
            "Oranges_pos3": 498.03,
            "Oranges_pos4": 496.67,
        },
        "Pears": {
            "Pears_pos1": 497.62,
            "Pears_pos2": 498.46,
            "Pears_pos3": 497.54,
            "Pears_pos4": 497.95,
        }
        };
        
 let output = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, outerKey) => {
      for(let [key, value] of Object.entries(input[outerKey])){
          acc.push([outerKey, value, key.split('_')[1]]);      
      }
      return acc;
 }, []);
 
 console.log(output);
```

Comment: Works great. Thanks for your speedy response.

Comment: @dfahsjdahfsudaf Also, don't use callbacks, return the result of `$.ajax(...)` and use `retrieveJSON(…).then(callback)`. Much more flexible and expressive to leverage the promises.

Comment: Okay. Thanks so much. Is there a way to delete the word and underscore before the pos? So instead it would become .. [["Apples", 501.82, "pos1"], ["Apples", 502.61, "pos2"], ["Apples", 502.61, "pos3"], ["Apples", 502.16, "pos4"]?

Comment: @plalx sorry one more question! What if the data set is like "Apples": {
            "Apples_pos1": 501.82,
            "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
            "Apples": 502.61,
            "Apples": 502.16,
        }? If the key contains "_pos" then do  key.split('_')[1]], but if there isn't "_pos" it just returns the key. So I would want the output to be [["Apples", 501.82, "pos1"], ["Apples", 502.61, "pos2"], ["Apples", 502.61, "Apples"], ["Apples", 502.16, "Apples"].

Comment: @dfahsjdahfsudaf can you open another question?

Comment: @mickl https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61147343/if-else-key-split-json

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this by using a for...in loop, or any type of loop. Then look up the value from the data by doing `data[nameOfKey]`.

```js
const fruitList = {
  "Apples": {
    "Apples_pos1": 501.82,
    "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
    "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
    "Apples_pos4": 502.16,
  },
  "Bananas": {
    "Bananas_pos1": 495.73,
    "Bananas_pos2": 493.27,
    "Bananas_pos3": 493.38,
    "Bananas_pos4": 494.34,
  },
  "Oranges": {
    "Oranges_pos1": 497.35,
    "Oranges_pos2": 497.31,
    "Oranges_pos3": 498.03,
    "Oranges_pos4": 496.67,
  },
  "Pears": {
    "Pears_pos1": 497.62,
    "Pears_pos2": 498.46,
    "Pears_pos3": 497.54,
    "Pears_pos4": 497.95,
  },
}

function reformat(fruitList) {
  let formattedFruits = "";
  for (fruit in fruitList) {
    for (fruitPosName in fruitList[fruit]) {
      const fruitValue = fruitList[fruit][fruitPosName];
      formattedFruits += `\n {"${fruit}", ${fruitValue}, "${fruitPosName}"}`
    }
  }

  return formattedFruits
}

console.log(reformat(fruitList))
```