# If else key split JSON

Tags: javascript, json

I have this function:

```js
let input = {
  "Apples": {
    "Apples": 501.82,
    "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
    "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
    "Apples": 502.16,
  }
};

let output = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, outerKey) => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(input[outerKey])) {
    acc.push([outerKey, value, key.split('_')[1]]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```

I need help editing it. What I want is if the key contains "_pos" then do key.split, if the key doesn't contain "_pos" leave it how it is.

My desired output is

```js
[
 ["Apples", 501.82, "Apples"], 
 ["Apples", 502.61, "pos2"], 
 ["Apples", 502.61, "pos3"], 
 ["Apples", 502.16, "Apples"]
]
```

Comment: What you are looking for is the `indexOf()` method.

Comment: Why don't you just implement exactly what you have described in your post? Use key.indexOf to check if _pos is contained

Comment: Your `input` is incorrect so there is no way to produce output you desire. `input.Apples` should be an array of objects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`||`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Logical_Operators#Short-circuit_evaluation) to handle the undefined.

```js
let input = {
  "Apples": {
    "Apples": 501.82,
    "Apples_pos2": 502.61,
    "Apples_pos3": 502.61,
    "Apples": 502.16,
  }
};

let output = Object.keys(input).reduce((acc, outerKey) => {
  for (let [key, value] of Object.entries(input[outerKey])) {
    acc.push([outerKey, value, key.split('_')[1] || key]);
  }
  return acc;
}, []);

console.log(output);
```